# Select an index of a list depending on percentage

Tags: java, random, percentage

Say I have a list of percentages:

List percentages = {52.3, 7.7, 20.0, 20.0};

How could I go about selecting one of these dependent on their percentage? For example, index 0 (52.3) has a 52.3% chance of being selected, whereas index 2 and index 3 would both have 20% chances of being selected.

Thanks in advance!

(I need to be able to access the index of the selected value)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should post what you have tried so far and tell us where you're stuck. :)

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: The words to google is "binary search".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Random;
public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    Double[] percentages = {52.3, 7.7, 20.0, 20.0};
    int index = pickRandom(percentages);
    System.out.println(index);

 }

 public static int pickRandom(Double[] list) {
    // Returns random index of list 
     Random r = new Random();
     Double randomPercentage = r.nextDouble() * 100;
     double sum = 0;
     int index = 0;
     for(Double d : list) {
         sum += d;
         if(sum > randomPercentage) {
             return index;
         }
         index += 1;
     }
     return index;
 }
}
```

Let's break down what's happening here. You supply pickRandom() an array of Doubles. We create a Random object to generate a random value (randomPercentage) between 0 and 100. Then we iterate through the list summing the elements until we exceed the randomPercentage and return the index of where we are.